# Constructing a list that has default items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not really sure how to word it, which is probably why Google has not been helpful. But say I have the following:

```
a = ['begin', 'end']
for x in range(10):
  a.insert(-1, x)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['begin', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'end']
```

How would I make a list that equals the output above with a list comprehension with the default items `['begin', 'end']`?

**Edit:**

What I meant by default items was that regardless of the numbers between "begin" and "end", which you could use a list comprehension to generate, the "begin" and "end" would always be where they are.

The closest answer to my question was @whackamadoodle3000 who essentially did the following although not exactly:

```
result = ['start'] + [x for x in range(10)] + ['end']
```

The source of my confusion was that I thought I could do all that in a list comprehension something like:

```
result = [['start'] + [x for x in range(10)] + ['end']]
```

Plus I forgot you could merge lists with the addition operator.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "with a list constructor"? What do you mean by "default items"? If you want to write a function, can you show what calling the function would look like?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work at all.

Comment: It sounds like your problem might just be the bugs in your example code - you forget to save the list to the `x` variable, and your loop should be `for a in ...` instead of `for x in ...`, since your loop body refers to the loop variable as `a`, not `x`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean default items. Do you mean a list-like object that returns a default value rather than an `IndexError` if the index is our of range?

Comment: @user2357112 I apologies for the unclear question. I have edited it along with the faulty example code.

Answer (score 2):

```
default = ['begin', 'end']
result = [default[0]] + [x for x in range(10)] + [default[1]]
```

This should work

Comment: How about `result = [default[0]] + [x for x in range(10)] + [default[1]]`

Comment: Ok, made the edit

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a function that yields "start" and "end" on either side of the provided iterable.

```
def markedrange(iterable, markers=('start', 'end')):
    yield markers[0]
    yield from iterable
    yield markers[1]

print(list(markedrange(range(10))))
print(list(markedrange(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], markers=('hi', 'bye'))))
```

result:

```
['start', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'end']
['hi', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'bye']
```

If you are on an older python version and you don't have `yield from`, you should instead yield in a loop.

e.g.

```
for i in iterable:
    yield i
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this works for 3.3+ only.

Comment: No problem. I think it is not exactly what you want, as it does not use a list comprehension (?). However it has the advantage that it does not require the creation of temporary lists to append to the start and end of the generated list.

Comment: @PaulRooney Originally I was tring to see if I could do it all in a list comprehension, but your answer does provide another angle which is most appreciated.